# AngularJS get json field name

Tags: angularjs, json, field-names

I started learning AngularJS a few days ago, and I wonder how do I get the name of a field in a JSON file.

```
{contador: "1159273", Code: "TCP_MISS/200", $$hashKey: "object:12"}
```

Thats one line of the json file, and I want to get the "contador" and "Code".
My objective is to do a table with that on top.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr >
      <td ng-repeat="(key, name) in $ctrl.logs.data">{{key}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="linha in $ctrl.logs.data">
      <td>{{ linha.contador }}</td>
      <td>{{ linha.Code }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

The "key" returns 0 1 2 ... and I want to get "contador" and "Code".

Comment: But is it impossible to get the names?

Comment: where is $ctrl.logs.data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your data is an array change this line

```
 <td ng-repeat="(key, name) in $ctrl.logs.data">{{key}}</td>
```

with the following

```
<td ng-repeat="(key, name) in $ctrl.logs.data[0]">{{key}}</td>
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/6GX2nJE3HQjUMLaPy6Yr?p=preview)**

Comment: it's possible to make it even more "automated"? Because I have other route that the JSON has other names, and I want to use the same page. `{{ linha.Code }}` is for this JSON, but I have other one that is `{{ linha.Method }}`.

Comment: Ok... I just did It... Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I am glad I was able to help.